Jackson Polymorphism using ID.DEDUCTION
I have a class hierarchy which I try to serialize and deserialize. I understand that the easiest way to go about it is using Id.DEDUCTION - I'm trying to make it work on the following code but I get exceptions, any idea?
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({ //
    @Type(CustomTask.class), //
    @Type(ExtendedTask.class) //
})
class abstract Task {

  private final long id;
  private final long threshold;
  private final List<Integer> params;

  public Task(long id, long threshold, List<Integer> params) {
    this.id = id;
    this.threshold = threshold;
    this.params = params;
  }
}

public class CustomTask extends Task {

  @JsonCreator
  public CustomTask(
    @JsonProperty("id") long id, 
    @JsonProperty("tHd") long threshold, 
    @JsonProperty("prms") List<Integer> params) {

    super(id, threshold, params);  
  }
}

public class ExtendedTask extends Task {

  private final int count;

  private final List<Long> inventory;

  @JsonCreator
  public ExtendedTask(
    @JsonProperty("id") long id, 
    @JsonProperty("tHd") long threshold, 
    @JsonProperty("prms") List<Integer> params,
    @JsonProperty("cnt") int count,
    @JsonProperty("inv") List<Long> inventory) {

    super(id, threshold, params);  
    this.count = count;
    this.inventory = inventory;
  }
}

When I try to deserialize the following JSON string:
{"id":9,"tHd":0,"prms":[200, 204, 208]}
it throws an InvalidTypeIdException exception telling me that there are 2 candidates match.
if I deserialize the following JSON string:
{"id":9,"tHd":0,"prms":[200, 204, 208],"cnt":1000,"inv":[1000,1001,1002]}
then it works well and creates an instance of ExtendedTask as expected.
The thing is that since both derived classes share some of the same properties than it cannot determine which class to instantiate - is there a better way to solve this?
Thank you!

I tried using:
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.DEDUCTION, defaultImple=CustomTask.class) @JsonSubTypes({ //     @Type(ExtendedTask.class) // })
and it overcomes the exception and actually deserializes the objects, but any type of json string it allocates as ExtendedTask and assign null value to the unknown field which beats the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish.
